# Error accessing a module function

Tags: function, module, lua, require

I have a problem with basic module usage in Lua. I have one file "helloworld.lua" and a second file "main.lua". I would like to call a function from the first file inside the second file. But I am getting an error:

> attempt to call field 'printText' (a nil value)

My actual code is below. Can someone tell me where the problem is?

helloworld.lua

```
local module = {}

function module.printText() 
    print("Hello world")
end

return module
```

main.lua

```
hello = require("helloworld")

hello.printText()
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Possibly another conflicting helloworld module without a `printText` function?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is the right way to do it.  This could be a problem if there is a conflicting `helloworld` module, or if you have a running lua state and are modifying the files without starting a new one.

`require` will only load the module passed with a string once.  Check `package.loaded["helloworld"]`.  You can set this to nil so that require will load the file again:

```
package.loaded["helloworld"] = nil
hello = require("helloworld") -- will load it for sure
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my problem! There was conflicting module without print method.